# Confused About Rudin's Opening Statements on his Chapter on Distributions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, distribution-theory

I have a few doubts regarding Rudin's opening paragraphs in Chapter 6 of *Functional Analysis*. The passage (with small edits) reads:

> A complex function $f$ is said to be locally integrable if $f$ is measurable
> and $\int_K |f| < \infty$ for every compact $K \subseteq R$. We let $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of all $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ whose support is compact. Then
>
> 1. $\int f\phi$ exists for every locally integrable $f$ and for every $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$.
> 2. $\mathcal{D}$ is sufficiently large to assure that $f$ is determined (a.e.) by the integrals $\int \phi f$. (To see this, note that the uniform closure of $\mathcal{D}$ contains every continuous function with compact support.)
> 3. If $f$ happens to be continuously differentiable, then
>    $$\int f'\phi = -\int f\phi' \ \ \ \ (\phi\in\mathcal{D}).$$
> 4. If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then
>    $$\int f^{(k)}\phi = (-1)^k\int f\phi^{(k)} \ \ \ \ (\phi\in\mathcal{D}).$$
>    The compactness of the support of $\phi$ was used in these integrations by parts.

**Regarding 2:** while it is true that the uniform closure of $\mathcal{D}$ contains all continuous functions with compact support, how does that imply $f$ is determined by the $\int \phi f$?

**Regarding 3:** it seems to me that the actual equation should be
$$\int f'\phi = f\phi -\int f\phi' \ \ \ \ (\phi\in\mathcal{D}).$$
Why does Rudin omit the $f\phi$ term?

**Regarding 4:** again, it seems to me the actual equation should be
$$\int f^{(k)}\phi = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-1)^if^{(i)}\phi^{(k-i-1)} + (-1)^k\int f\phi^{(k)}.$$
Why does Rudin omit the second term?

**Lastly:** how is compactness of the support of $\phi$ used?

Comment: The integrals here are definite integrals (from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$). That should explain 3) and 4).

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh of course. That does solve the issue!

Comment: You are asking too many questions simultaneously. When you ask a question you should wait for an answer, study the answer and then ask the next one.

Answer (score 1):

The second remark ($\mathcal{D}$ being *sufficiently large* to determine $f$ a.e. through its various integrals) alludes to the following fact: if $f$ and $g$ are locally integrable with respect to a $\sigma-$finite Borel measure $\mu$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f\phi \, d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} g\phi \, d\mu \qquad \text{ for all } \phi \in \mathcal{D},$$
then $f = g$ a.e.[$\mu$].

To prove the above statement, it's enough to show that if
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f\phi \, d\mu = 0 \qquad \text{ for all } \phi \in \mathcal{D}$$
then $f = 0$ a.e.[$\mu$]. Suppose there is an open interval $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is positive a.e.[$\mu$] on $A.$ Take $K \subset A$ a (nondegenerate) proper compact subinterval (so that $\mu(A \smallsetminus K) > 0$) and pick a nonnegative $\phi \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subset A$ and $\phi = 1$ on $K$ (you can always construct these smooth *bump functions* using smooth *cutoff functions*). Then
$$0 = \int_\mathbb{R} f\phi \, d\mu = \int_A f\phi \, d\mu = \int_K f\phi \, d\mu + \int_{A \smallsetminus K} f\phi \, d\mu \, > \, \int_K f \, d\mu.$$
This contradicts the positivity a.e.[$\mu$] of $f.$ A similar argument works for $f$ negative a.e.[$\mu$], and thus we conclude that $f$ must be zero a.e.[$\mu$] on any open interval, and also on $\mathbb{R}.$

The third and fourth remarks are explained by noting that the *boundary terms* in the integration-by-parts formula always vanish since every $\phi \in \mathcal{D}$ has compact support.

Lastly, you want the functions $\phi \in \mathcal{D}$ to have compact support so the integrals $\int_\mathbb{R} f\phi$ are all finite for every locally integrable $f$ (and because of the nice "topological/real analysis" properties that you get when you work with these function spaces).

Comment: I'm a little confused on the following implication. "$f$ is not positive a.e. or negative a.e. on any open interval" $\implies$ "$f$ is zero a.e. on every open interval." Could you expand on this step?

Comment: What if for every open interval, $f$ is positive over some set of nonzero measure, and also zero or negative over some set of nonzero measure? Is this impossible?

Comment: Actually, now I think the implication is false. I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763163/can-mathbb-r-be-partitioned-into-two-sets-with-positive-measure-on-every-inte) question, which was motivated by my comments above, and people have pointed to the existence of functions which contradict this implication.