# Can $\mathbb R$ be partitioned into two sets with positive measure on every interval?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers, borel-sets

An answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748241/confused-about-rudins-opening-statements-on-his-chapter-on-distributions) post got me wondering: Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is Borel measurable, and let $B = \mathbb R \setminus A$. Is it possible that, for every nonempty open interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, we could have $\lambda(A \cap I) > 0$ and $\lambda(B \cap I) > 0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure? Please provide an example or proof of impossibility.

Comment: Yes, its possible, this actually just got asked the other day, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762446/1210477